# Javascript to modify html from external site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've been researching for about 2 days now and am all out of ideas. I'm new to javascript but from what I have read it seems that my problem has to do with cross-site scripting rules/precautions. My goal is simple make a website based on an external site (which I have no control over). I want to use javascript or some other method to load a website's html and then remove tags etc. I looked at ajax but ran into issues with same-domain restrictions. I tried a "hack" by including the website in a hidden iframe and trying to access the code that way but sandboxing seems to prevent that. I really want to do this with web based techniques. Any advice or tips on how to handle this (or is it impossible)?

Comment: What do you mean by "*website's html*"?

Comment: Why are you hacking? executing script form external site doesn't sound good? what can be a reason? think about your design again bruvoo! there is something called `CORS` look into it as well `:))`

Comment: I believe I tried cors but I couldn't get it work. I believe the server side needs to support it? And I'm not trying to hack I'm basically trying make a script that given a URL will get the HTML from that page and make it "mobile friendly" by dumbing down the code and removing unnecessary stuff. In the end I will just end up with an HTML file on my local machine with the dumbed down code. I am in no way trying to break into websites.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have a simple server-side process that will make the request to the other site for you, retrieve its HTML and return that to you.

Then you just make an AJAX request to your server side method and when it returns, you will have access to the other website's HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I mentioned I'm completely new to web development stuff. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction in regards to how to make a server side process?

Comment: Unfortunately that is too broad a topic to cover in a single answer. First, you need to decide on what server side technology you wish to use: PHP, NodeJS, ASP.NET, Java, Ruby on Rails, Python, etc. Whichever you decide to go with will determine how to create a URL that is AJAX-friendly for you to communicate with from the Javascript. I'm afraid such an open ended question is best solved with some Google research, it's unlikely that someone on StackOverflow will do everything for you. They more help you out when you are stuck at a certain point.